# Can anyone recommend video lectures on all subjects of physics for a masters student?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am a student of Physics doing masters in it and I am looking forward to study on my own. By own I mean with video lectures, books etc. It would be really kind of you all if you could recommend me some good books and video lectures on each subjects I will come across.

Comment: One of my favorite lecture series is Leonard Susskind Stanford cosmology series https://youtu.be/P-medYaqVak .  Then when you need a comedic break from that, check out Stanford’s Robert Sapolsky series https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL848F2368C90DDC3D

Comment: have a look at the graduate mit open courses https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/

Comment: Hi Jadoo ki jhappi. Welcome to Phys.SE.  This post (v2) seems _too broad._ Note that res. recom. qs. are restricted on Phys.SE.

Comment: As the question specifically asks about "video lectures", I will add that I have recently started a video series on quantum mechanics (level: advanced undergraduate/graduate). So far it is under construction (8 videos), and happy to take suggestions. The format is: videos of 10-20 min which are relatively self-contained but playlists form sequences of videos to be watched in order. Some vidoes have associated Jupyter notebooks with code for you to play with. Link: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZqRWM99ixVKA-ydebf_tMQ/featured

Comment: I am actually following ur lectures Prof M